# Passing functions return value to another function

Tags: python-3.x, function

I have created a function that retrieves information from a device and then places credentials in to a dictionary. This is then returned as a dictionary value.

When i run another functions using this information it works but it seems to run the other function again as i am getting the same output from the first function.

One of its tasks is to connect and then tell you how many devices there are. It does that first time

Connection to 10.1.42.23 is working
A total of 1 Routers have been tested and connected
Would you like to continue? y

But then when it moves on to the next function using the dictionary that has been returned it says it again and adds 1 to it, like its re running the other function

If you do a test function just to print the returned dictionary it will print it correctly and the function works, but it re runs the other function first - I think !

I have tried looking to see if the function that is causing the issue is re run in the code again but its not

ADDITIONAL AFTER COMMENTS - Thanks all for the comment, below should be enough for you to see what i am trying to do

```
def main():

    device_connection_test_to_switches()

    ! calls a function to display a menu and asks for you to make a choice
    choice = input("Select an Option: ")
    if choice == "1":
        choice1_input = input("Are you sure you want to run the full audit? ")
        choice1_input = choice1_input.lower()
        if choice1_input == "y" or choice1_input == "yes":
            full_audit()
        else:
            print("Not a valid option try again!")

def full_audit():

    create_running_configs_switches(device_connection_test_to_switches())



def device_connection_test_to_switches():
    ! 50 lines of code that results in creating a dictionary
    return switch_dict
    wb.save("Network_Audit.xlsx")

def create_running_configs_switches(switch_dict):
    cv = 1
    for k, v in switch_dict.items():
        connection = ConnectHandler(**v)
        run_conf_out = connection.send_command("show run")
        connection.disconnect()
```

Comment: Would you share the code, at least sufficient parts of it to make people reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry i am new, and when i put bulks of code in it said the formatting was incorrect

Comment: @dancullen, then please format them [correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Thanks i have edited my post